# Create MEF part with Constructor parameters

Tags: c#, mef

I have a class that export

```
[Export(typeof(IService))]
```

this class has a constructor that accept

```
Dictionary<string, object>
public MyService(Dictionary<string, object> model){}
```

this is how I create parts

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add("c:\\[SomePath]"));   
Container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);   
Container.ComposeParts(this);
return Container.GetExportedValue<IService>();
```

How do I go about injecting my paramter into my constructor when the part is exported ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Container.ComposeExportedValue(model);
```

Assuming `model` is the `Dictionary<string, object>` that you want to inject.

Then you need to decorate the constructor for `MyService` with:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public MyService(Dictionary<string, object> model){}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I tried, but when my code calls
return Container.GetExportedValue<IService>();
it calls the default (empty) c-tor

Comment: @Pacman, have you added the ImportingConstructor attribute? I have just tested the code provided and it works